# python gtk toggle combobox?

Tags: python, combobox, gtk

Is the equivalent of ToggleButton exist in PyGtk ?
I would like to have a callback like: `True or False`.

```
self.liste = gtk.ComboBox(self.liststore)
self.liste.connect("changed", self.result_list)
```

With this method, the program can't detect if the user clicks again on the same choice.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the standard GTK [ToggleButton](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktogglebutton.html)?

Comment: My program has a "compact mode"... And I'm using a combobox instead of buttons to display the results, so the window can be more little

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific advice as I haven't used ComboBox much, but I'm pretty sure that what you want to do is possible.

The [GTK tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-ComboBoxAndComboboxEntry.html) says

> ComboBox uses a TreeModel (usually a ListStore) to provide the list
>   items to display.

The basic ComboBox methods are great for simple things, but for more advanced usage you need to play with things at the TreeModel level yourself. To do that effectively, you need to know how they work; fortunately the docs in the tutorial are pretty good: [TreeView widget](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html), but also check out the info in the reference manual.

To make the equivalent of a toggle button you can use [14.4.8. Activatable Toggle Cells](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-CellRenderers.html#sec-ActivatableToggleCells)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look here. I'll tell you if it works. If I can't, I will maybe add a simple button "remove the last choice". Thanks again

Comment: If you have problems, post your code, either here or in a new question. I'm no expert with TreeView, but I have used it a few times. Unfortunately, I don't currently have access to most of my Python code (I'm on holiday), so it's not so easy for me to post example code.